# Bayesian inference - Pi notation

Tags: bayesian, notation

I often see people use $\pi(\theta|y)$ and $\pi(\theta)$ for posterior distribution and prior, respectively. e.g.

### $\pi(\theta|y) \propto f(y|\theta)*\pi(\theta)$

sometime, the notation is simply written as

### $p(\theta|y) \propto p(y|\theta)*p(\theta)$

I would like to know when $\pi(x)$ and $p(x)$ can be used interchangeably.

ps. I believe that there is no significant difference between $p(x)$ and $f(x)$. It only depends on one's preference; however, $p(x)$ might be more precise since it explicitly states that it is a probability distribution.

Comment: You can use $p(x)$, $p(\theta|x)$ etc if you want. The $\pi()$ just reminds us that we are working within the Bayesian framework

Comment: @jcken thank you :)

Comment: I asked quite [similar](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515340/px-mid-theta-as-function-of-x-or-function-of-theta), you may track. Good to know the interest for Bayesian is still there.

Answer (score 1):

Citing Gelman *et al.* [http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/book/](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/%7Egelman/book/) (page 20), where the second formula is always used:
"Some authors use different notations for distributions on parameters and observables—for example, $\pi(\theta), f(y|\theta)$—but this obscures the fact that all probability distributions have the same logical status in Bayesian inference. We must always be careful, though, to indicate appropriate conditioning; for example, $p(y\theta)$ is different from $p(y)\,.$"